# Which wood is better for fencing STK Cedar or Knotty Eastern White Cedar

Tags: wood, fence

The below prices are in CAD

Home Depot has both varieties
Porcupine 1x6x8' STK Cedar S4S Fence =$9.42
Irving 1x6x8 Knotty Eastern White Cedar =$10.20

The Lowes version of the same board

Top Choice 1 x 6 Western Red Cedar Fence Board S4S -seems to be square on all sides -$9

Interesting that the pictures show the wood square (Lowes) and rounded (HD) for the same finish S4S

Google says:
Western Red Cedar Select Tight Knot Grade. This grade has a lot of personality and is used on siding , interior paneling and virtually any application. The knots and other natural features define the visual character of this grade. In this grade the knots are sound and tight.

Comment: you have not asked an actual question ....... the last paragraph implies that you are asking which fence you will like better

Comment: I don't think so. The last paragraph shows what I could find out about WRD STH googling... nothing else